# Finding if a set of lines exists in a large text file

Tags: python, linux, windows, bash, shell

How do i find out the intersection of 2 files in windows?

TextFile A: 100GB
TextFile B: 10MB

All i can think of is using python

I would read the lines in textfile B into memory in python and compare with each line in text file A.

I was wondering if there is any way to do it via the command prompt in linux/windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If repetition doesn't matter, then this command will do it:

`sort <(sort file1 | uniq) <(sort file2 | uniq) | uniq -d`

Comment: Hi could you explain what does it do.

Comment: @aceminer, so you don't care if the smaller file isn't all together in the larger one?